# Model class not found in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Vendor

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie to `laravel`. I have created project and created table like

```
php artisan make:migration create_vendors_table
```

Then I created model like

```
php artisan make:model Vendor
```

I modified my table and did migration. Tables are successfully got created in MySQL. But when I tried to hit http://localhost:8000/api/v1/register then I am getting following issues:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Class &#039;Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Vendor&#039; not found in file /Users/sandeeparmal/clients/ForCity/code/webservices/php_api/forcity_web_api/app/Vendor.php on line 8
```

I tried to find Vendors file in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\` but it's not available there.

Here is my Vendor.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Vendor as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class Vendor extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasApiTokens;

    protected $guard = 'vendors';
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'api_key',
    ];
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Here is my auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'vendors',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport', 
            'provider' => 'vendors',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'vendors' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Vendor::class,
        ],
    ],
```

Here is my AuthController.php

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\Vendor; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Validator;
class AuthController extends Controller 
{
 public $successStatus = 200;

 public function register(Request $request) {    
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
              'name' => 'required',
              'email' => 'required|email',
              'password' => 'required',  
              'number' => 'required', 
    ]);   
    if ($validator->fails()) {          
        return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()], 401);                        
    } 

    $input = $request->all();  
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
    $vendor = Vendor::create($input); 
    $success['token'] =  $vendor->createToken('AppName')->accessToken;
    return response()->json(['success'=>$success], $this->successStatus); 
}


public function login(){ 
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
    $vendor = Auth::vendor(); 
    $success['token'] =  $vendor->createToken('AppName')-> accessToken; 
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
    } else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}

public function getVendor() {
    $vendor = Auth::vendor();
    return response()->json(['success' => $vendor], $this->successStatus); 
 }
}
```

I also tried composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `use` statement should be:

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`

not this

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Vendor as Authenticatable;`

Comment: but I have vendor table and I have created Vendor model then?

Comment: It is not necessary. You must use as User because it is provided by Laravel and available in `auth` package of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You have just choose to not use `User` model for authentication, As you want to use build in authentication feature of laravel but with a custom Model, your `Vendor` Model must extends `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` which will provide to `Vendor` model. All authentication fonctionality and method use during authentication by Laravel and not `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Vendor` which doesn't exists (`Illumiate\Foundation\Auth` is a laravel's namspace` not yours)

Even if you create your custom `Vendor` class it can't be in the Illuminate\Foundation\Auth` namespace which is namespace use by laravel, you only have access to namespace which you create and not namespace for third party library.